# How to include shaders as external files

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, webgl

Is there a way to include this shader code as an external *vertexShader.js* without quotes and include between "script" tags?

```
var vertCode =
'attribute vec3 coordinates;' +

'void main(void) {' +
' gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);' +
'gl_PointSize = 10.0;'+
'}';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You asked how to include shaders as **external files**

There are several ways but first off it's important to note that using backticks for strings which are called [*multiline template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) let you have multiline strings

```js
const str = `
this
string
is
on
multiple lines
`;
```

So there's no need to use 'this' + 'that' as you were doing.

If you really want to put them in separate files though then here's at least 3 of the many ways you could do it

- put them in separate script files, assign to some global. Example

  vertexShader.js

  ```
    window.shaders = window.shaders || {};
    window.shaders.someVertexShader = `
    attribute vec3 coordinates;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;'
    }
    `;
  ```

  in your html

  ```
    <script src="vertexShader.js"></script>
    <script>
     // use shader as window.shaders.someVertexShader
     ...
    </script>
  ```

  Note that your final JavaScript script could also be in a separate file just as long as it comes after the shader files.
- Put them in a separate JavaScript module

  Modern browsers support [ES6 modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)

  vertexShader.js

  ```
    export default `
    attribute vec3 coordinates;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;'
    }
    `;
  ```

  In this case your JavaScript script **must** be in an external file so your
  HTML might look something like this

  ```
    <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
  ```

  and main.js would look something like this

  ```
    import someVertexShader from './vertexShader.js';

    // use someVertexShader
  ```

  There's an example [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/nice-swift)
- Load them with [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

  In this case there's no JavaScript in the shader file

  vertexShader.shader

  ```
    attribute vec3 coordinates;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;'
    }
  ```

  Then in your script

  ```
    fetch('./vertexShader.shader')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((shaderSource) => {
       // use shadeSource
    });
  ```

  The biggest problem with this method is the scripts are downloaded asynchronously so you have to manually wait for them to download. Using async/await that's pretty easy though.

  Imagine you wanted to download 6 shaders files and then use them. This code would wait for all 6 files to download before starting

  ```
    function loadTextFile(url) {
      return fetch(url).then(response => response.text());
    }

    const urls = [
      './someShader1.shader',
      './someShader2.shader',
      './someShader3.shader',
      './someShader4.shader',
      './someShader5.shader',
      './someShader6.shader',
    });   

    async function main() {
      const files = await Promise.all(urls.map(loadTextFile));
      // use files[0] thru files[5]
    }
    main();
  ```

If it was me and I really wanted to put my shaders in external files I'd probably use `import` and then either only target modern browsers or else use some program like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) to package them into a single file for shipping. This is what [THREE.js](https://github.com/mrdoom/three.js) currently does.

Answer (score 8):

You can add the shader code to a `<script>` tag of type `"x-shader/x-vertex"` for the vertex shader and `"x-shader/x-fragment"` for the fragment shader.
See also [WebGL and HTML shader-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020151/webgl-and-html-shader-type)

```html
<script id="my_vertex_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 coordinates;
 
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
</script>

<script id="my_fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
// fragment shader code
</script>
```

The shader code can be "loaded" with ease:

```js
var vertCode = document.getElementById("my_vertex_shader").text;
var fragCode = document.getElementById("my_fragment_shader").text;
```

[WebGL - is there an alternative to embedding shaders in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878703/webgl-is-there-an-alternative-to-embedding-shaders-in-html) may be of interest, too.

Comment: thank's fixed it